# Asp.Net application with DropBox not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I set the DropBox application type Full DropBox; I set on my application the following function:

```
Private Const AppKey As String = "my key"
Private Const AppSecret As String = "my secret"
Private Function Upload() As String
Dim client As DropNetClient
Dim token As UserLogin
Dim userToken As String = My.Settings.userToken
Dim userSecret As String = My.Settings.userSecret
Dim needAccessToken As Boolean = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userToken) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(userSecret))
If (needAccessToken) Then
    client = New DropNet.DropNetClient(AppKey, AppSecret)
    client.UseSandbox = True
    client.GetToken()
    Dim url = client.BuildAuthorizeUrl()
    Try
        token = client.GetAccessToken()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Exception! " + ex.Message)
        Exit Function
    End Try
    userToken = token.Token
    userSecret = token.Secret
    My.Settings.Properties.Item("userToken").DefaultValue = userToken
    My.Settings.Properties.Item("userSecret").DefaultValue = userSecret
    My.Settings.Save()
Else
    client = New DropNet.DropNetClient(AppKey, AppSecret, userToken, userSecret)
    client.UseSandbox = True
End If
Dim rawData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("") + "/Fax/" + "Fax.zip")
Dim result As MetaData = client.UploadFile("/", "fax.zip", rawData)

End Function
```

Unfortunately education `tokens = GetAccessToken ()` I get the error:

> Received Response [Unauthorized]: Expected to see [OK]. The HTTP response was [{" "error" ":" "Request token has not been properly authorized by a user. ""}] ".

I checked the URL (`client.BuildAuthorizedUrl ()`) and returns me "Unauthorized".

How can I link to Dropbox folder? I do something wrong? Or do I need to set better application of Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the URL via `BuildAuthorizeUrl`, you need to send the user to that address and have them authorize your app. Only once they've done that can you call `GetAccessToken`.

The error you're seeing is because you're trying to get the access token before the user has actually authorized your app.

Comment: I put in the code Dim clientToken = client.GetToken() and then 'Dim url = client.BuildAuthorizeUrl(clientToken, "http:\\localhost\myapp)', but I get the form that asks me to click to allow ...

Comment: Right. Then you (the user) should click "Allow", and then your app can get an access token.